# TransportException - Composer trying to download file from my API... NOT FOUND

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I am getting a TransportException when I run composer update on Ubuntu using a fresh install of Laravel Forge.

```
forge@trust-dale-production-V2:~/default$ composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information


[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://api.github.com/repos/amcardwell/trust-dale" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

I am able to run a composer install... and I can use git connect to my git repo and push/pull. Here is an output of composer diag:

```
forge@trust-dale-production-V2:~/default$ composer diag
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.yangqi/htmldom : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: FAIL
Missing pubkey for tags verification
Missing pubkey for dev verification
Run composer self-update --update-keys to set them up
Checking composer version: OK
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didnt have a github oauth token linked yet. Thanks :)